# Need help finding correct pattern to be used in snowpipe copy into command

Tags: snowpipe

Need help on copy into pattern in snowpipe.
facing challenge while using pattern for below file present in s3 bucket folder S3bucket/Folder/files

```
1)changes_tags.csv.12345
2)changes_tags.csv.987987
3)tags.csv.67587
4)tags.csv.9987
```

to load tags.csv file, in snowpipe copy into command using pattern=`.*tags.csv.*`, but it is loading changes_tags.csv file also.

```
created external stage at folderlevel,
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE s3_stage
STORAGE_INTEGRATION = s3_int
ENCRYPTION          = ( TYPE = 'SNOWFLAKE_SSE' )
URL                 = 's3://bucketname/folder'
FILE_FORMAT         = csv_pipe_format;
```

please find below snowpipe command

```
create or replace pipe TAGS  auto_ingest=true as
COPY INTO CHANGE_TAGS(tag_id
tag_name ,
tag_value 
filename ,
file_rownum 
)
FROM (select $1,$2,$3,METADATA$FILENAME,METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER from @s3_stage) 
PATTERN='.*tags.csv.*'
ON_ERROR = 'CONTINUE'
FILE_FORMAT =   (TYPE = 'CSV',FIELD_DELIMITER = ',',SKIP_BLANK_LINES = TRUE,FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"');
```

Comment: If your file name starts with tags,csv, then you can use ```pattern=tags.csv.*```. Not sure why you are prefixing .* when you dont want to consider anything before tags.

Comment: @pankaj, i have tried, but data not loaded into table.

Comment: How about ```pattern=.*/tags.csv.*``` ? The idea is to create an expression to just have file-name you need. You will also need to include '/' as part of expression and .* to include any path portion before your file-name.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below test-case, to show file exclusion/inclusion, using pattern -

- Outputs are truncated for bravity

To upload file named - MOCK_DATA.csv -

`copy into mock_data_tab from @sf_s3_stage pattern='.*/MOCK_DATA.*';`

| file | status | rows_parsed | rows_loaded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s3://snowflakepr/csv/data/MOCK_DATA.csv | LOADED | 1001 | 1001 |

Changed file name and added a prefix, to test exclusion from copying -

`list @sf_s3_stage;`

| name |
| --- |
| s3://snowflakepr/csv/data/Prefix_MOCK_DATA.csv |

Trying to copy  -

`copy into mock_data_tab from @sf_s3_stage pattern='.*/MOCK_DATA.*';`

| status |
| --- |
| Copy executed with 0 files processed. |

As can be seen from above no file gets copied.

If we use pattern .* as prefix it will pick all (not desired) -

`copy into mock_data_tab from @sf_s3_stage pattern='.*MOCK_DATA.*';`

| file | status | rows_parsed | rows_loaded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s3://snowflakepr/csv/data/Prefix_MOCK_DATA.csv | LOADED | 1001 | 1001 |